# Jquery is changing data during ajax Post... why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

I have an object that looks like this:

```
var data = {
  "to" : "someone@abc.com",
  "attachment" : [{"file": "somefile.jpg"}, {"file": "someOtherFile.jpg"}]
}
```

Then I post it with $.ajax like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://myHostHere.com",
    data: data,
    success: function(data){
      console.log("Success...");
    }
});
```

On my server (Node.js with Express4) the received object comes out looking like this:

```
{
"to" : "some@abc.com",
"attachment[0][file]" : "somefile.jpg",
"attachment[1][file]" : "someOtherFile.jpg"
}
```

I have tried setting `processData: false` on the $.ajax call and that doesn't work.

Why is my "Attachments" node, an array of objects, being converted into these string names on my server? Is Jquery doing this? How do I stop this behavior?

Since "attachments" could be an array of random length I nned to be able to loop over on the server side.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Look in your browser tools at the POST request data - it should already be in this format. You are not sending an object, but a query, which precedes the invention of JSON and the client can not assume that the backend will understand JavaScript objects. This format can be understood by virtually any backend technology that can process POST requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

> **data** 
>   Type: PlainObject or String or Array 
>  
>   Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string.

Therefore, in order to send the JSON object as is, you need to create a String that contains the json:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://myHostHere.com",
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    success: function(data){
      console.log("Success...");
    }
});
```

Comment: Awesome Thanks!! ... When I added `JSON.stringify()` it still didn't work... But adding the contentType fixed it.  Thanks Again!